# How to create a populated form for editing in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form that I'd like to have autopopulated with the object for editing.

My form snippet is as follows:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form_block">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help_text">{{ field.help_text }}</p>
        {% endif %}
        {{ field }}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="error">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there an easy way to create a snippet like this that adds object content when it's available to the form? Or, do I need to recreate the edit form with the values explicitly described?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) or `ModelForm`

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import *

>>> class UserForm(forms.Form):
>>>     username = forms.CharField()
>>> print unicode(UserForm(initial={'username':'foo'}))
<tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="username" value="foo" id="id_username" /></td></tr>


>>> class UserModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
>>>     class Meta:
>>>         model = User
>>>         fields = ['username']
>>> print unicode(UserModelForm(instance=User(username='foo')))
<tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" value="foo" maxlength="30" /><br /><span class="helptext">Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters</span></td></tr>
```

Comment: The second option is much better, especially as it means you can call save afterwards.

Comment: this looks close, but how would I do it with the db object when I call `instance` in the edit view?

Comment: now that I think about it this won't work. The form doesn't know what record in the DB that I want.

Comment: @DaveMerwin just pass the model instance you want to populate  to the instance parameter.

Comment: I do that. But in the snippet, how do I access that instance? I'm thinking that I'm going to have to just write a custom edit template.

Comment: Turns out I have to just create the custom edit form. Bummer.

Comment: @DaveMerwin ah, I missed the last but one of your msg, sorry. If you are in editing mode, you should know the object to be edited, in the view, right?